# How to do a factory of const objects

Tags: c++, c++11

This is not a question about dlib, but a question on how to implement a feature on dlib.

[Dlib](http://dlib.net/) has a virtual class `dlib::tensor`, and an implementation of it named `dlib::alias_tensor_instance`. Objects of this class are constructed by calling `operator()(dlib::tensor &original, size_t offset)` on the factory class `dlib::alias_tensor`, that will create a `dlib::alias_tensor_instance` pointing to a internal slice of the `original` tensor, that can be used wherever a tensor is required, without actually copying it.

Since it is very common to `const dlib::tensor&` to be passed around, I am interested on a overload of the factory operator taking a const:

```
<something> operator()(const dlib::tensor &original, size_t offset);
```

Trouble is, neither I nor the author knows how it can be done properly. Do you guys knows of any solution? Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/204).

EDIT: As @Angew remarked, the returned type must derive and implement `dlib::tensor`, so it can be used where `const dlib::tensor&` is needed.

Comment: What requirements are there for the lifetime of the return value? Would it be feasible to have it immovable?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question, but the const reference would be passed around, and it will be destroyed before the original.

Comment: I tried to write an answer based on my understanding of the requirements. If it's totally off the mark, please let me know.

Comment: You posted the link, but you should really add the information about the need for a "`const` base-class" access to the question itself; it's an important requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias_const_tensor_instance` cannot safely derive from `tensor`.

Instead it owns a tensor and exposes an implicit `operator tensor const&()`.

This may not work perfectly in some narrow contexts involving SFINAE template magic code, but for most cases it will work seemlessly.

It may require glue code within `alias_const_tensor_instance` to replicate the *entire const API* of `tensor` and forward it to the owned tensor.  Or you can force users to call a `tensor const& get() const` method or `tensor const* operator->() const` or `tensor const& operator*() const`, which enforces DRY.

Myself, I'd be tempted to make it a pseudo-pointer type with `->` and `*` overloads rather than duplicate the const API.

Comment: I like very much this idea. Seems very simple, and the only drawback is that the user will have to make a member access to use the object. It is not an awful drawback, at least not for my needs.

Comment: The way it was actually implemented, a proxy class implicitly convertible to `const dlib::tensor&` was used.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to create a `alias_const_tensor_instance`, return a `const` version of it, and make it non-movable:

```
struct alias_const_tensor_instance
{
  alias_const_tensor_instance(const alias_const_tensor_instance&) = delete;
  alias_const_tensor_instance(alias_const_tensor_instance&&) = delete;
  alias_const_tensor_instance& operator= (const alias_const_tensor_instance&) = delete;
  alias_const_tensor_instance& operator= (alias_const_tensor_instance&&) = delete;

  // ... whatever else is needed
};

const alias_const_tensor_instance operator() (const dlib::tensor &original, size_t offset) {
  return { /*something*/ };
}
```

Since the class is neither copyable nor movable, and is returned `const`, it can only be received by the caller like this:

```
const alias_const_tensor_instance &i = factory(tensor, size);
```

This makes sure that no non-`const` instance of `alias_const_tensor_instance` can exist, but it limits it to be passed around as `const&`.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3d48ccfa6417f12)

Comment: So how does this get returned from the factory? Prior to C++17, even ellided copies or moves require the relevant constructor to exist, I think. And in any case, what is the point of ensuring that this class can't be relocated?

Comment: @KyleStrand The return value is constructed in-place (note that brace-init-list in the return statement), and is received by reference on the calling side. Which means it will never be copied around.

Comment: I don't quite get it. If caller receives a reference, where the object's memory is allocated? In caller's stack?

Comment: ....the signature does not return it by reference, and brace-initialization does not change whether a copy occurs when returning the value....

Comment: I don't see how this works. Could you run it through e.g. [Coliru](coliru.stacked-crooked.com) with a complete code example please?

Comment: @rubenvb Live example added.

Comment: @lvella The standard doesn't say (it doesn't use terms like "stack"). It just guarantees that it works. In practice, yes, it will be in the caller's stack frame (just like any other return value, in fact).

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, brace initialisation **does** change it. When you use a brace-init in a `return` statement, it does not initialise a temporary from which the return value would be constructed (as all other return statements do), it initialises the return value directly. And when the caller takes it by `const &`, they get a reference directly to the return value. No copy or move necessary.

Comment: @Angew how is the lifetime of the referenced object defined? It smells like a dangling reference (const refs to temporaries normally only live until the end of a statement/function call/whatever).

Comment: @rubenvb No, when a temporary is bound directly to a reference, the lifetime of that temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference (with a few exceptions). Google "most important `const`." The code is 100% safe.

Comment: Right, in C++11 and on, [according to Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db7b402bbe39b07). Cool trick. I like.

Comment: @rubenvb The "`const &` extends temporary lifetime" was present in C++03 as well (and 98 probably too). But the "brace-init initialises returned value directly" rule was not; that's new in C++11.

Comment: @Angew I haven't read anything about how brace-initialization changes the behavior of `return` statements. Do you know where in the standard this behavior is described?

Comment: Also, I'm still unclear on what the point of ensuring that this class can "never be copied around" (which in any case is what I meant by "never be relocated" in my first comment). What is the benefit of this?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because once you allow copying/moving a class `X`, there is **no** way of ensuring instances of `const X` can exist but instances of (non-const) `X` can't. And the premise is that the `alias_...` class in question must not exist in a non-const form, otherwise we'd lose compile-time operation safety which want to maintain. Basically, the class wants to derive from `const BaseClass` only, but since C++ doesn't support that, the best we can do is derive from `BaseClass` and make sure no non-const objects exist.

Comment: @KyleStrand The best I can find is C++11 [stmt.return] 6.6.3/2: "A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object
or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer
list."

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a new type (`alias_const_tensor_instance` as in Angew's answer) that represents an alias for a constant tensor, and make all the *internal data members* `const`. This way, there are no restrictions on what can be done with the alias itself, but it can't be used to modify the tensor.

Comment: It's hidden behind the link in the question, but the problem is that the alias must derive from something and will be used as a stand-in for this base class. So it must be ensured that non non-`cosnt` instance of the alias itself exists.